# How to render multiple shortcode in a single wordpress page withount html and css conflicts?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm new to this platform,

I'm currently dealing with difficulties in displaying multiple shortcodes on a single WordPress page. Despite my attempts, I'm running into conflicts with both CSS and JS. Specifically, only the first shortcode seems to apply the JS and CSS properly. If there is more than one shortcode, the JS doesn't seem to take effect. I'm struggling to pinpoint where the issues might be arising. Any assistance in identifying and resolving these conflicts would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

=> wp_enqueue_scripts code where I put localized script variables:

```
function ww_loan_calculator_front_scripts()
{
    $post_content = get_post_field('post_content');

    // Use preg_match_all to match all instances of the shortcode

    preg_match_all('/\[loan_calculator id=(\d+)(?: title=(?:"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'|([^"\']+))?)?]/', $post_content, $matches);

    // Get unique post IDs
    $post_ids = isset($matches[1]) ? array_unique($matches[1]) : array();

    $loan_all_setting_data = get_option('ww_loan_option');

    if ($post_ids) {
        foreach ($post_ids as $post_id) {

            $loan_all_setting_data = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ww_loancalc_value', true);

            wp_register_script('loan-calculator-jquery-ui-' . esc_attr($post_id), 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

            // CHART JS
            wp_register_script('loan-calculator-chart-js-' . esc_attr($post_id), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/chart-js/chart.js', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

            // Font awesome
            wp_register_style('loan-calculator-font-awesome-script-' . esc_attr($post_id), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/css/all.min.css', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION);

            // Custom CSS and JS
            //01/05/23
            wp_register_style('loan-calculator-new-theme-style-' . esc_attr($post_id), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . '/includes/admin/forms/theme-templates/new-theme/css/style.css', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION);

            wp_register_script('loan-calculator-print-script-' . esc_attr($post_id), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/jquery.print.js', array('jquery'), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

            wp_register_style('loan-calculator-frontend-style-' . esc_attr($post_id), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/css/frontend-style.css', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION);

            wp_register_script('loan-calculator-frontend-script-' . esc_attr($post_id), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/frontend-script.js', array('jquery'), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

            wp_register_script('loan-calculator-frequency-payment-' . esc_attr($post_id), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/frequency_payment.js', array('jquery'), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

            // Get setting data for the specific post ID
            
            // Fetch Loan Calculator setting data from option table and pass in script.

            $currency_symbols = ww_loan_get_currency_symbol();

            $loan_amount_min_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_min_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_min_value'] : "";
            $loan_amount_max_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_max_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_max_value'] : "";
            $loan_term_min_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_min_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_min_value'] : "";
            $loan_term_max_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_max_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_max_value'] : "";
            $monthly_rate = isset($loan_all_setting_data['monthly_rate']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['monthly_rate'] : "";
            $application_fee = isset($loan_all_setting_data['application_fee']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['application_fee'] : "";
            $back_ground_color = isset($loan_all_setting_data['back_ground_color']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['back_ground_color'] : "";
            $interested_rate = isset($loan_all_setting_data['interested_rate']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['interested_rate'] : "";
            $interest_rate_min_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_min_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_min_value'] : "";
            $interest_rate_max_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_max_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_max_value'] : "";
            $calculation_fee_setting_enable = isset($loan_all_setting_data['calculation_fee_setting_enable']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['calculation_fee_setting_enable'] : "";
            $remove_decimal_point = isset($loan_all_setting_data['remove_decimal_point']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['remove_decimal_point'] : "";
            $payment_mode_enable = isset($loan_all_setting_data['payment_mode_enable']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['payment_mode_enable'] : "";
            $regular_repayment_heading = isset($loan_all_setting_data['regular_repayment_heading']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['regular_repayment_heading'] : "";
            $default_balloon_amount = isset($loan_all_setting_data['ballon_per']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['ballon_per'] : "";
            $disable_ballon_amt = isset($loan_all_setting_data['disable_ballon_amt']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['disable_ballon_amt'] : "";
            $select_theme = isset($loan_all_setting_data['select_theme']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['select_theme'] : "";
            $month_label = __('Months', 'loan-calculator-wp');
            $year_label = __('Years', 'loan-calculator-wp');
            $interest_label = __('Interest', 'loan-calculator-wp');
            $principal_label = __('Principal', 'loan-calculator-wp');

            // Setting data is passed in js file using Localize 
            $setting_data = array(
                'loan_amount_min_value' =>  $loan_amount_min_value,
                'loan_amount_max_value'   => $loan_amount_max_value,
                'loan_term_min_value'      => $loan_term_min_value,
                'loan_term_max_value' => $loan_term_max_value,
                'monthly_rate' => $monthly_rate,
                'application_fee' => $application_fee,
                'back_ground_color' => $back_ground_color,
                'interested_rate' => $interested_rate,
                'interest_rate_min_value' => $interest_rate_min_value,
                'interest_rate_max_value' => $interest_rate_max_value,
                'calculation_fee_setting_enable' => $calculation_fee_setting_enable,
                'currency_symbols' => $currency_symbols,
                'remove_decimal_point' => $remove_decimal_point,
                'month_label' => $month_label,
                'year_label' => $year_label,
                'interest_label' => $interest_label,
                'principal_label' => $principal_label,
                'default_balloon_amount' => $default_balloon_amount,
                'disable_ballon_amt' => $disable_ballon_amt,
                'payment_mode_enable' => $payment_mode_enable,
                'select_theme' => $select_theme,
                'regular_repayment_heading' => $regular_repayment_heading
            );

            wp_localize_script('loan-calculator-frontend-script-' . esc_attr($post_id), 'setting_data', $setting_data);
        }
    } else {
        wp_register_script('loan-calculator-jquery-ui', 'https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

        // CHART JS
        wp_register_script('loan-calculator-chart-js', WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/chart-js/chart.js', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

        // Font awesome
        wp_register_style('loan-calculator-font-awesome-script', WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/css/all.min.css', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION);

        // Custom CSS and JS
        //01/05/23
        wp_register_style('loan-calculator-new-theme-style', WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . '/includes/admin/forms/theme-templates/new-theme/css/style.css', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION);

        wp_register_script('loan-calculator-print-script', WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/jquery.print.js', array('jquery'), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

        wp_register_style('loan-calculator-frontend-style', WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/css/frontend-style.css', array(), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION);

        wp_register_script('loan-calculator-frontend-script', WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/frontend-script.js', array('jquery'), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

        wp_register_script('loan-calculator-frequency-payment', WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_URL . 'includes/js/frequency_payment.js', array('jquery'), WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_VERSION, true);

        // Get setting data for the specific post ID

        // Fetch Loan Calculator setting data from option table and pass in script.

        $currency_symbols = ww_loan_get_currency_symbol();

        $loan_amount_min_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_min_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_min_value'] : "";
        $loan_amount_max_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_max_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_amount_max_value'] : "";
        $loan_term_min_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_min_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_min_value'] : "";
        $loan_term_max_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_max_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['loan_term_max_value'] : "";
        $monthly_rate = isset($loan_all_setting_data['monthly_rate']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['monthly_rate'] : "";
        $application_fee = isset($loan_all_setting_data['application_fee']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['application_fee'] : "";
        $back_ground_color = isset($loan_all_setting_data['back_ground_color']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['back_ground_color'] : "";
        $interested_rate = isset($loan_all_setting_data['interested_rate']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['interested_rate'] : "";
        $interest_rate_min_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_min_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_min_value'] : "";
        $interest_rate_max_value = isset($loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_max_value']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['interest_rate_max_value'] : "";
        $calculation_fee_setting_enable = isset($loan_all_setting_data['calculation_fee_setting_enable']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['calculation_fee_setting_enable'] : "";
        $remove_decimal_point = isset($loan_all_setting_data['remove_decimal_point']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['remove_decimal_point'] : "";
        $payment_mode_enable = isset($loan_all_setting_data['payment_mode_enable']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['payment_mode_enable'] : "";
        $regular_repayment_heading = isset($loan_all_setting_data['regular_repayment_heading']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['regular_repayment_heading'] : "";
        $default_balloon_amount = isset($loan_all_setting_data['ballon_per']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['ballon_per'] : "";
        $disable_ballon_amt = isset($loan_all_setting_data['disable_ballon_amt']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['disable_ballon_amt'] : "";
        $select_theme = isset($loan_all_setting_data['select_theme']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['select_theme'] : "";
        $month_label = __('Months', 'loan-calculator-wp');
        $year_label = __('Years', 'loan-calculator-wp');
        $interest_label = __('Interest', 'loan-calculator-wp');
        $principal_label = __('Principal', 'loan-calculator-wp');

        // Setting data is passed in js file using Localize 
        $setting_data = array(
            'loan_amount_min_value' =>  $loan_amount_min_value,
            'loan_amount_max_value'   => $loan_amount_max_value,
            'loan_term_min_value'      => $loan_term_min_value,
            'loan_term_max_value' => $loan_term_max_value,
            'monthly_rate' => $monthly_rate,
            'application_fee' => $application_fee,
            'back_ground_color' => $back_ground_color,
            'interested_rate' => $interested_rate,
            'interest_rate_min_value' => $interest_rate_min_value,
            'interest_rate_max_value' => $interest_rate_max_value,
            'calculation_fee_setting_enable' => $calculation_fee_setting_enable,
            'currency_symbols' => $currency_symbols,
            'remove_decimal_point' => $remove_decimal_point,
            'month_label' => $month_label,
            'year_label' => $year_label,
            'interest_label' => $interest_label,
            'principal_label' => $principal_label,
            'default_balloon_amount' => $default_balloon_amount,
            'disable_ballon_amt' => $disable_ballon_amt,
            'payment_mode_enable' => $payment_mode_enable,
            'select_theme' => $select_theme,
            'regular_repayment_heading' => $regular_repayment_heading
        );

        wp_localize_script('loan-calculator-frontend-script', 'setting_data', $setting_data);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ww_loan_calculator_front_scripts');
```

this is js enqueque code where i put add_shortcode function

```
    public function ww_loan_calculator_shortcode_fn($atts, $content = null)
    {
        // Default attributes
        $atts = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'id' => '',
                'title' => '',
            ),
            $atts,
            'loan_calculator'
        );

        // Apply filter on ww_loan_calculator_all_setting_data

        $loan_calculator_all_setting_data = get_option("ww_loan_option");

        $loan_all_setting_data = apply_filters('ww_loan_calculator_all_setting_data', $loan_calculator_all_setting_data, $atts);

        if ($atts['id'] || $atts['title']) {

            $select_theme = isset($loan_all_setting_data['select_theme']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['select_theme'] : "";

            // If repayment chat is enabled then only enqueue chart js
            if (isset($loan_all_setting_data['enable_repayment_chart']) && $loan_all_setting_data['enable_repayment_chart'] == 1) {

                // Chart JS
                wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-jquery-ui-' . esc_attr($atts['id']));
                wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-chart-js-' . esc_attr($atts['id']));
            }
            $disable_font_awesome = isset($loan_all_setting_data['disable_font_awesome']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['disable_font_awesome'] : "";

            // If Disable font awesome is disable then only enqueue font awesome CSS
            if (empty($disable_font_awesome)) {
                // Font Awesome
                wp_enqueue_style('loan-calculator-font-awesome-script-' . esc_attr($atts['id']));
            }

            // Custom JS
            wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-frontend-script-' . esc_attr($atts['id']));
            // wp_add_inline_script('loan-calculator-frontend-script');
            wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-frequency-payment-' . esc_attr($atts['id']));
            wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-print-script-' . esc_attr($atts['id']));

            // Output content based on the theme
            $html = '';

            if ($select_theme == 'new_theme') {
                ob_start();
                wp_enqueue_style('loan-calculator-new-theme-style-' . esc_attr($atts['id']));
                include(WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_ADMIN . '/forms/theme-templates/new-theme/ww-loan-calculator-loan-new-theme-form.php');
                $html .= ob_get_clean();
            } else {
                ob_start();
                wp_enqueue_style('loan-calculator-frontend-style-' . esc_attr($atts['id'])); // Add this line to enqueue the frontend style
                include(WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_ADMIN . '/forms/theme-templates/default-theme/ww-loan-calculator-loan-default-theme-form.php');
                $html .= ob_get_clean();
            }
        } else {

            $select_theme = isset($loan_all_setting_data['select_theme']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['select_theme'] : "";

            // If repayment chat is enabled then only enqueue chart js
            if (isset($loan_all_setting_data['enable_repayment_chart']) && $loan_all_setting_data['enable_repayment_chart'] == 1) {

                // Chart JS
                wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-jquery-ui');
                wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-chart-js');
            }
            $disable_font_awesome = isset($loan_all_setting_data['disable_font_awesome']) ? $loan_all_setting_data['disable_font_awesome'] : "";

            // If Disable font awesome is disable then only enqueue font awesome CSS
            if (empty($disable_font_awesome)) {
                // Font Awesome
                wp_enqueue_style('loan-calculator-font-awesome-script');
            }

            // Custom JS
            wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-frontend-script');
            wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-frequency-payment');
            wp_enqueue_script('loan-calculator-print-script');

            // Output content based on the theme
            $html = '';

            if ($select_theme == 'new_theme') {
                ob_start();
                wp_enqueue_style('loan-calculator-new-theme-style');
                include(WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_ADMIN . '/forms/theme-templates/new-theme/ww-loan-calculator-loan-new-theme-form.php');
                $html=ob_get_contents(); 
                $html .= ob_get_clean();
            } else {
                ob_start();
                wp_enqueue_style('loan-calculator-frontend-style'); // Add this line to enqueue the frontend style
                include(WW_LOAN_CALCULATOR_ADMIN . '/forms/theme-templates/default-theme/ww-loan-calculator-loan-default-theme-form.php');
                $html=ob_get_contents(); 
                $html .= ob_get_clean();
            }
        }
        // Close the main container div

        return $html;
    }

    
        // Add Calculator Shortcode
        add_shortcode('loan_calculator','ww_loan_calculator_shortcode_fn');
```

shortcode add in page :

[image: shortcode add in page]

output:

[image: front output]

Comment: Hi Nilesh and welcome to SO. There is no point in loading the same script or styles twice as you only need it once. So I would make the scripts generic by default like you do in your `else` block of the enqueue file. All the specific variables could either be fetched from within the shortcode callback or passed via attributes. Then output the variables as JSON in your shortcode HTML so you can parse the data with JS per shortcode output.